# Изменить value у кнопки через jQuery

Tags: jquery

Не могу разобраться как менять value у кнопки, везде написано что так:
`$("#btn17").text("Свернуть");`
Не работает.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn17").click(function(){
            $("#p_text17").css("display","none");
            $("#btn17").text("Свернуть");
            $("#p_text_long17").slideDown(200);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span4">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <p id="p_text17">Короткий текст</p><br>
    <p style="display: none;" id="p_text_long17">Длинный текст</p>
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="btn17" value="Развернуть"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btn17").click(function(){
            $("#p_text17").css("display","none");
            $("#btn17").val("Свернуть");
            $("#p_text_long17").slideDown(200);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span4">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <p id="p_text17">Которткий текст</p><br>
    <p style="display: none;" id="p_text_long17">Длинный текст</p>
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="btn17" value="Развернуть"/>
</div>
```